# How to handle all the different sizes and resolutions of Images for Retina and Non-Retina iPhone & iPad for the Web

Tags: image, ipad, resolution, retina-display

Apple.com recently changed their web images to accomodate the new iPad's retina display by doubling the size of their images. example:

**non-retina.jpg:** http://images.apple.com/home/images/ipad_hero.jpg [1]
**retina_2x.jpg:** http://images.apple.com/home/images/ipad_hero_2x.jpg [2]

Though both images have set in html to `width="1381" height="575"`.
Does it suffice to rename the enlarged image with a _2x for the browser to fetch the appropriate image, similarly to the `@2x` for images in Apps?

[1]: Non-Retina image with size: 1454 x 605
  [2]: Retina image with size: 2908 x 1210

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not enough to just create a `_2x` image. Apple uses custom script to make that work. It's described here:

http://cloudfour.com/how-apple-com-will-serve-retina-images-to-new-ipads/

It's not an ideal solution, as it wastes bandwidth downloading regular-sized image first, and makes extra requests to the server.

---

How to serve high-dpi images is an open question. There's some unofficial discussion about this at W3C:

http://www.w3.org/community/respimg/

---

Adding `width` and `height` dimensions to `<img>` that are half of image's real pixel size is a good way to serve high DPI images, although it is going to waste some bandwidth on regular-DPI screens.

You might want to [enable better image interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Image-rendering) when you use that.